# Android fragment popBackStack and isDetached()

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I want to perform some action in previous fragment when current fragment is popped from backstack.
Suppose this is how my back stack is now

Fra_A --> Fra_B --> Fra_C --> Fra_D

I'm calling `fm.popBackStack()` which removes `Fra_D` and this calls my `OnBackStackChangedListener` within which I have given

```
if(manager.findFragmentByTag("Fra_D").isDetached()){
    my_function();
}
```

I'm always getting **NullPOinterException** in this line. I know its because there is no fragment in the name `Fra_D` now.

Is there a way to find which fragment is being popped??

Answer (score 0):

i guess  count of fragments can  help you:

```
int backStackEntryCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
```